# Custom data segments update

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, bezier-curves, vertex-groups

I am developing an addon where I need store segments curve data.

I store that info in a curve propertie as a dictionary where the keys are the segments and the value are the data that I need to retrieve.
The problem comes when some operation that adds or removes segments is done on the curve because my dictionary for segments info is not updated.

I have thought to develop a modal that 'listen' every time some of that operations are done and then update the data. But I don't think is a clean solution. 
I need something like the vertex groups with data meshes but Blender doesn't have it for curve points.

Have anyone any Idea how can I solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: For what operation do you need the curves data and why can't you just "regrab" it when you need it?

Comment: I store info about each segment on a curve. That info could be whatever (rgb color, a string...). If some operation is done on the curve that remove or add a new segment, the old info that I stored is not correct because the segments on the curve have changed.

Comment: Why did you change the tags, the were great before! This question has nothing to do with [vertex-groups]. Please consider rolling this edit back.

Comment: @Leander I just got an msg about approving tag changes and clicked "yes"  :)

Comment: Hm, but don't you agree that the "curves" tag is much better than the "vertgex-groups" tag. You can "roll back" the revision here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/179152/revisions by clicking on rollback on the original post.